# $w = ax = by$ over the nonzero integers $\implies w = \pm\text{lcm}(a,b)\gcd(x,y)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

Suppose, $a,b,x,y$ are nonzero integers such that $w = ax = by$.  Then $ w = \pm\text{lcm}(a,b)\gcd(x,y)$.

Proof.  If $a, b = \pm 1$, then $\gcd(x,y) = \pm x = \pm y = w$.  Let that be a base case for induction on the number $n$ of first few primes involved in forming $a, b$, ie. ($n = 0$ here).  Now assume it's true for the first $n$ primes ie. If $a,b = \pm $ some composition of the first $n$ primes and $x, y$ are any nonzero integers, then the theorem is true.  Now introduce the next prime $p$.  Any number composed of the first $n+1$ primes only can be written as $pz$ where $z$ is composed only of the first $n$ primes.  Let $a,b$ be such numbers, then if $w = a'x = b'y = ap^{c}x = bp^{d}y$ and $d\geq c$ wlog, then $\dfrac{w}{p^c} = a x = b(p^{d-c}y)$ and note that $p^{d-c}$ must divide $x$ since $a$ is composed only of the first $n$ primes.  Then by induction $\dfrac{w}{p^c} = \pm \text{lcm}(a,b) \gcd(x, p^{d-c} y) = \pm \text{lcm}(a,b) p^{d-c} \gcd(x,y)$ so $w = \pm \text{lcm}(a,b) p^d \gcd(x,y) = \pm \text{lcm}(ap^c, bp^d) \gcd(x,y) = \pm \text{lcm}(a', b')\gcd(x,y)$. $\square$

Is that right?